# What is the most accurate method to find a delta dependent on epsilon in this Real Analysis problem?

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

Let $f(x)=5x^2-5$ and $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Find a $\delta$ s.t. $0<\delta<1$ so that $|x-1|<\delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(1)| < \epsilon$. For $\epsilon=.2$, find one  such $0<\delta<1$.

What is the optimal solution for this problem? Here is my work:

Let $\delta = 1/2$. $|x-1| < 1/2$, so $x+1<7/2$.
$|5x^2-5|=5|x+1||x-1|<5(7/2)|x-1|<\epsilon.$
So,
$|x-1|<2\epsilon/35$. Finally, $\delta=min\{1/2,2\epsilon/35\}$

When $\epsilon=.2$, $\delta=.0114$.

Comment: What do you mean by optimal?

Comment: Is there a better way to answer this problem?

Comment: Note that the Q of the 1st paragraph does not require you to find the largest possible $\delta$ for a given $\epsilon.$  For example if $x=1+y$  with $|y|< 1$ then $|f(x)-f(1)|=|10 y+5y^2|\leq 10|y|+5|y^2|<10|y|+5|y|$ $=15|y|.$  Therefore if $\delta=\min (1, \epsilon /15)$  then $|x-1|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(1)|<\epsilon.$

Comment: I actually am supposed to solve for the largest possible $\delta$. Does my method above work for that?

Answer (score 1):

Here we have $5x^2 - 5 = 0$ when $x = 1$

So for an $\epsilon = 0.2$, we need to solve the inequality $|f(x)-f(1)|<0.2$

$|5x^2 - 5 - 0| < 0.2$

$-0.2 < 5x^2 - 5 < 0.2$

$4.8 < 5x^2 < 5.2$

$.96 < x^2 < 1.04$

$0.9798 < x < 1.0198$

Hence $\delta_1 = .0202$ and $\delta_2 = .0198$

It is the general rule to take the smaller of the two deltas to ensure that both inequalities are met. If $.0202$ were used, then $5(1.0202)^2 - 5 = 0.204 > 0.2$.